# How can i parse a string to datetime in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a string 02/12/2022 06:53:43 and i want to parse it to a datetime to perform the following check

```
 string myDate = "02/12/2022 06:53:43";
 DateTime.Parse(myDate).AddMinutes(-2) < DateTime.UtcNow)
```

But it gives an error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can i parse the date ?

Comment: Other than the syntax error, [can't reproduce this error](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mc7jiA), please post a [mre], and look at using DateTime.TryParseExact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this 12th of Feb or the 2nd of December? ;)

You could use `ParseExact`. There are plenty examples in [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0).

Here something that works for your format, assuming it's the 2nd of December.

```
var dateString = "02/12/2022 06:53:43";
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("02/12/2022 06:53:43", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There's a double colon in your pattern, and the original code worked just fine.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, I correct.

Comment: OP: If your date is the second of December, this format will work. If your date is the twelfth of February, you will need to change it to `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.